# Survival to Creative Button in SurvivalCraft

Tags: survivalcraft

Is there a button in survivalcraft, where you can swich from survival to creative; or vise versa without using mods?

Answer (score 1):

You can change the type of game by editing the world from the menu. Just tap where it says Survival and change it to Creative or Harmless. You can't change it during a game though.